# Xcode command-line build doesn't find embedded framework at compile time. Why not?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

It feels like this question has been asked a few times before, but usually involving 'pods' or other complicating factors.  For the purposes of this question, I have simplified the context.

Using Xcode 8.3.3, I created two projects .. an iOS app called "A" and a framework called "F".  The app uses the framework (there is an `import F` statement in one source file of "A") so "F" needs to be embedded in "A".  Everything is Swift, no Obj-C.

The "A" project contains the "F" project and "F" is a "Target Dependency" (sorry, not revealed in this screenshot, but it's true) so it looks like this:

[image]

All the project settings in "A" and "F" are default values, and specifically
 `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` is blank, apart from the addition of the "Copy Files" phase to embed "F" into "A" at build time.

That's the setup, here's the problem:  a build by **Xcode** completes successfully (compiles without error and embeds "F" in "A"), but a command-line **xcodebuild** build fails, at compile time, because the `import F` doesn't find "F":

```
 . . /A/A/ViewController.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'F'
```

My much larger, real, non-sample project has been migrated up through Xcode versions from a long way back .. fearing some version skew (for example, the "Embed Frameworks" build phase of old, is now just a "Copy Files" phase), I created this simple example case using only Xcode 8.3.3.

It would seem to me that **Xcode** and **xcodebuild** should compile the same, regardless of some other build-time variations: Xcode builds a 'debug' and xcodebuild builds a 'release'; and the results of their work end up in different places, Xcode in "DerivedData" (deep in `~/LibraryXcode/`) and xcodebuild in a `build` folder alongside the "A" project file.

Why does xcodebuild fail to satisfy the `import F` when Xcode has no trouble with it?  Thanks for any insights.

EDIT: added zipped projects .. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqfifh0qt4jlm5b/A%2BF.zip?dl=0

Comment: Can you please post your `xcodebuild` command? Also, if you can share your sample project it would be helpful, but not necessary.

Comment: My command is just a plain, no parameters, `xcodebuild` .. I'm in the "A" directory and the app is the (first) target.  I can note that "F" does get built first, as it should given the dependency.  I'll zip up the two project folders in a few minutes ..

Comment: .. further, I'll note that "F.framework" is built but it's placed in the "F" folder, where it can't be found; Xcode places it in the "A" folder, making it available to the `import F`

Comment: @RamsayConsulting Is your problem solved ???? I am facing same issue. Please let me know if you found any positive approach to solve it out.

Comment: Not resolved ..

Comment: By any chance, were you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, but using Cocoapods. I have a workspace containing 3 Xcode projects, and two of these are: a Cocoapods 'Pods' project, and project that builds MyFramework.framework. That framework builds against one of the pods (so because of the way Cocoapods works, the Framework project is importing a framework called Pods_MyFramework).

This builds when I'm within Xcode, but if I try to use Xcodebuild to build the MyFramework target, by specifying the workspace and target to xcodebuild, I get an error: "ld: framework not found Pods_MyFramework".

Comment: I was actually previously experiencing the same error ("ld: framework not found Pods_MyFramework") with the Xcode project itself, until I enabled the Pods-MyFramework scheme and manually built that. This seemed to place a concrete Pods_MyFramework file in the correct location, where Xcode seemed to think it was previously missing (red text in the Xcode navigator), and this was good enough for me. But now that I need to use xcodebuild to produce an XCFramework, I can't do anything to eradicate the error.

Comment: I feel as though the issue could be related to the fact that my intermediate frameworks (Pods_MyFramework) are built by Cocoapods into Derived Data, and xcodebuild maybe doesn't like that.